# What is wrong with the syntax in my code?

Tags: python-2.7

The error I get when running the code below is "There is an error in your program: Invalid Syntax", and the colon (:) after the statement "for file_name in file_list:" is highlighted. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the syntax?

```
import os

def rename_files():
    #(1) get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\users\ss2369\pictures\prank")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(r"C:\users\ss2369\pictures\prank"
    #(2) for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Comment: You need to close the brackets on the line `os.chdir(r"C:\users\ss2369\pictures\prank"`. Everything else looks OK.

Comment: Aaahg! Really dumb mistake. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:  os.chdir(r"C:\users\ss2369\pictures\prank"

You did not close the bracket. As far as I can tell this is the problem.  Compilers sometimes can't pick out exactly where the error occurs when it comes to syntax. If it's not on that line where the error is "called", it's usually somewhere close above.

Comment: Aaahg! Really dumb mistake. Thank you!!